# What is the significance of default schema that is created when we connect snowflake with dbt cloud

Tags: cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, dbt-cloud

While connecting snowflake from DBT Cloud, DBT uses a default schema. What is the significance of that schema.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

dbt Cloud (and more loosely, core) manages different environments by materializing models into different schemas in your Snowflake database.

When you develop using the dbt Cloud IDE and you run your models, dbt needs to materialize those models by creating tables/views in some namespace. By default, to keep different developers in separate namespaces, it uses a schema called `dbt_your_user_name`.

Note that the default behavior is different in the "deployment" feature of dbt Cloud. The jobs you configure there are intended for production, qa, and CI/CD runs, so you can configure the target schema separately.